# bash: echo string with special characters into a file

Tags: bash

I have looked all over but can't get anything to work for my situation.

I need to add a string to a file automatically (i.e., this will be called from a Dockerfile) but I can't figure out how to escape the special characters.

I need to add the the following exact string `push!(LOAD_PATH, "/home/ngsim_env/julia/AutoEnvs")` to a file `~/.juliarc.jl`. I tried escaping all the special characters as follows:

```
echo "push\!(LOAD_PATH, \"/home/ngsim_env/julia/AutoEnvs\")" >> ~/.juliarc.jl
```

but this gives the error `bash: push\!(LOAD_PATH, "/home/ngsim_env/julia/AutoEnvs"): No such file or directory`

This is all taking place inside a Docker Ubuntu 16.04 container and the output of `bash --version` is `GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: How are you running this command?

Comment: When working directly in the container I'm just executing `echo "push\!(LOAD_PATH, \"/home/ngsim_env/julia/AutoEnvs\")" >> ~/.juliarc.jl` in the terminal. But plan is to have this appear as `RUN echo ...` in the Dockerfile.

Comment: I'd use `echo '...'`, but I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Oh that totally worked (after removing escape slash on the inner double quotes), I could have sworn I tried that...thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

`echo 'push!(LOAD_PATH, "/home/ngsim_env/julia/AutoEnvs")' >> "$HOME/.juliarc.jl"`